# How to emulate Ctrl+C in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, signals

I have a Ruby script that contains an IO.popen call. I am able to cancel the popen call with CTRL+C (I use `Signal.trap("SIGINT")`, which then leads to me calling `kill -2 #{popen_pid}` ). This works fine, and when I press CTRL+C, the `kill -2` leads to the popen process running some cleanup before ending itself.

*My issue:* I would also like to be able to have this same behavior when the popen process takes too long. However, I am unable to emulate the CTRL+C behavior. Using `Process.kill` on the ruby script's pid ends up just ending everything without the cleanup happening, and running `Process.kill` on the popen process does nothing. I tried directly accessing shell using backticks, to call `kill -2` on the ruby script's pid and popen pid, but those don't do anything either.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was running into issues mostly because I wanted to print lines from the popen process as they were happening, but also having a timeout that would do a `kill -2` to encourage process cleanup.

In the end, I ended up starting a new thread alongside the popen call (but before I started printing stuff from the command), where the thread would call `kill -2` once the popen call took longer than my wait time:

```
Thread.new do
  $next_thread += 1
  this_thread = $next_thread - 1
  $active_threads[this_thread] = true
  start_time = Time.now
  while true
    break if not $active_threads[this_thread]
    minutes_elapsed = (Time.now - start_time) / 60
    if minutes_elapsed > 90
      inner_packer_pid = `ps -Af | tr -s ' ' | grep -v "grep" | grep "packer build" | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort | tail -n 1`.strip()
      `kill -2 #{inner_packer_pid}`
      cancel_build()
      break
    end
  end
  $active_threads[this_thread] = false
end

builders = Set.new

packer_build = IO.popen("packer build -color=#{not $is_no_color} #{spec_file} 2>&1")
$packer_build_pid = packer_build.pid
packer_build.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be difficult to get an answer about killing your processes especially when accessing the shell.  A solution on one platform might not work on other platforms.  Rather than trying to go through the hassle of killing your processes I would suggest using Timeout, if your IO.popen call takes longer than you want then you can do your cleanup in rescue.

```
require 'timeout'

seconds_to_wait = 10


begin
  block_result = Timeout.timeout(seconds_to_wait) do
    # your IO stuff
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Ain't nobody got time for that!"
  # do your clean up here
end
```

Comment: This works in stopping the popen call, but it essentially calls it with a -9 signal. I need -2, because the process needs to run some internal cleanup...